# inheritance, calling overloaded method from base method

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two classes:

```
class A {
    int get();
    string str();
}

string A::str() {
    return string_with( get() );
}

class B : public A{
    int get();
}
```

if I do:

```
A a
B b
b.str()
```

`b` will invoke `A::str()` (good) and it ill use `A::get()` method (bad!). I want, that when I invoke `b.str()`, the `B::get()` is used by `str`.

How to make it work?

Comment: There is no inheritance within the code you posted.

Comment: -1 the example code is not real. the question as-is is rubbish. it is impossible to say whether the *intended* question is meaningful or not.

Comment: added inheritance, my mistake. @Steinbach: this is intended question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it virtual. That's exactly what virtual is for.

Write

```
virtual int get();
```

in A's definition. And, just to make the code more understandable, do the same in B's.

By the way, I'm assuming that you meant to write `class B : public A`.

Comment: Good psychic debugging skills!

Answer (score 2):

In the magical word of Object-Oriented programming, there are two ways of calling a method: **static** and **dynamic** dispatch.

In static dispatch, the code called when you do something like `a.do_it()` is determined statically, that is, it is determined upon the type of the variable `a`.

In dynamic dispatch, the code called is determined dynamically, i.e., it is determined upon the type of the **object** referenced by `a`.

C++, of course, supports **both**. How do you tell the compiler which type of dispatch do you want? Simple: by default you have static dispatch, unless you put the `virtual` in the method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use virtual keyword. and then use pointer

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual int get() { cout << "A::get()" << endl; return 0;}
    string str()
    {
        cout << "A::str()" << endl;
        get();
        return "";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual int get() { cout << "B::get()" << endl; return 0; }
};
```

B* b = new B;
b->str();

the output:
A::str()
B::get()